# Implementing simple cache for POCO

Tags: c#, .net

What is the best way to map between id's and objects? For **example** having a class  OrderItemPreference having a properties PreferenceId < an id  and Preference . I want Preferences to read from Cache no quering the database.To get from a dictionary the preference object.Like preferencesDictionary[id] . Quering the database for each item is slow.Because each product would have 3-4 preferences  each one refering to a group ,too much data.Also writing the same mapping code again seems bad.

I can't and i dont want to use an ORM.

The simplest solution would be embedding in POCO's property the code to read from cache.But this doesnt seem correct to me. Any solution how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that you are using the repository pattern (you don't have to, but the idea is similar for other data access patterns):

```
interface IPocoRepository {
    Poco GetById(int id);
}

class DatabasePocoRepository : IPocoRepository {
    public Poco GetById(int id) {
        // read the POCO from the database
    }
}

class CachePocoRepository : IPocoRepository {
    private readonly IPocoRepository pocoRepository;
    public PocoCachingRepository(IPocoRepository pocoRepository) {
        this.pocoRepositry = pocoRepository;
    }

    public Poco GetById(int id) {
        // read from the cache
        // if available, return it
        // if not, load using pocoRepository and cache
    }
}
```

And now anywhere that you need a `PocoRepository` and want caching enabled, use the `CachingPocoRepository`. Obviously you need to write the cache policy.

Comment: Thank you for the pattern but my question is how to call it. I want to call for example Order.Table   < and Table to return Table object from cache using Order.TableId for example. Where should i put this code? Is it good to put it inside the property (Table)? . To load it manually in code would add complexity. Like in a loop to construct a report if i add code there to check if each item is loaded that would make code too complex..

Comment: The WHOLE point is that caching is not germane to the nature of the POCO object. It's germane to data access, and that's where the code should be: in your data access code and you consume in your data access layer.

Comment: So i should put that to my DAO code where i load the data?Thats seems better.

Comment: this may not work.When i get the objects from the WebService i get ids. I should somehow populate them again from cache.